# Convert three I;16B images into one image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have 3 images of type `I;16B` and I am correctly reading them into `Python` via `PIL`:

```
#!/usr/bin/en python

import sys 
from PIL import Image

mode2bpp = {'1':1, 'L':8, 'P':8, 'RGB':24, 'RGBA':32, 'CMYK':32, 'YCbCr':24, 'I':32, 'F':32}

if __name__=="__main__":
    print "Working!"

    basedir = sys.argv[1]
    imname = sys.argv[2]
    Rc = sys.argv[3]
    Gc = sys.argv[4]
    Bc = sys.argv[5]
    Zstack = sys.argv[6]

    Rtif = basedir+"/"+imname+"-"+Rc+"/Data-"+Rc+"-Z"+Zstack+".tif"
    Gtif = basedir+"/"+imname+"-"+Gc+"/Data-"+Gc+"-Z"+Zstack+".tif"
    Btif = basedir+"/"+imname+"-"+Bc+"/Data-"+Bc+"-Z"+Zstack+".tif"

    Rim = Image.open(Rtif)
    Gim = Image.open(Gtif)
    Bim = Image.open(Btif)

    print Rim 
    print Rim.mode
```

This shows me that the data is `I;16B` but I am having to read them as 3 different images (one per channel). How should I go about combining these 3 channels into one image and writing a `.tif` file as output?

Answer (score 0):

For now, Pillow doesn't support multichannel images with more than 8 bits per channel. You can only convert every image to 'L' mode and merge they together with `Image.merge()`.